# ERROR: View field webview collides with a variable or import file:///home/Abc/Android/app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_webview.xml Line:22

Tags: android, webview

I am getting this warning when build the app although app runs smoothly but don't want to see this warning below is the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="webview"
            type="com.example.rozkhabardhar.webview.WebviewFragment" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".webview.WebviewFragment">

        <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/swipe_web"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
            <WebView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/webview"></WebView>

        </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Below is the Warning i see while building app.

```
ERROR: View field webview collides with a variable or import file:///home/Abc/Android/app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_webview.xml Line:22
```

Answer (score 4):

Recently I was also getting this warning, I didn't knew what was wrong but thanks to your code and I noticed something!,
In your code the (id) of `WebView` View and databinding variable name are same i.e `webview`, this is causing the collision, change anyone and you are done!.